# connection failure with localhost server

Tags: apache

after installing apache in my pc I cannot visit `http://localhost`. 
firefox shows that :
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost.
what is the problem? can anyone help

Comment: what exactly is the error code from the browser?

Comment: #The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
    moments.
#If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
    connection.
#If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
    that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Comment: it may be error from path configuration.

Comment: actually apache was working, but when I update my avast anivirous, then suddenly it stops working.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your webserver.

Check http://kb.mozillazine.org/Error_loading_any_website .

There are many things that could go wrong in this case. My best bet is to check your proxy or firewall settings.

UPDATE:

Antivirus programs interfere with firewall and security settings, so you might take a look into that... Make sure the port that Apache is running is not blocked by your firewall. Go to the firewall settings and make sure that Apache (or HTTP port number used by Apache) is not blocked

Comment: I cant do it properly... lack of knowledge about it

Comment: Now I can access localhost. but when I want to visit htdocs folder then again facing the same prob

Comment: what URL are you invoking?

Comment: my created website. by the way I get a window in firewall which has a list of Allowed Programs and features. beside the name of any program there is 2 check box, one for public, one for private. Is it the window I need to work? and in that window there is no apache. for including apache which specific file should I choose?

Answer (score 0):

In windows if you installed apache you have to start your apache service first then go throw your Firefox or other browser simply type local host then you can access your server.